# not being able to get past 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x

```
text = "X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475";
a = text.find(': ')
print (a)
b = text.find('"',a)
print (b)
c = text.find[a+1 : b]
print (c)
d= c.strip()
print(d)
```

----> 6 c = text.find[a+1 : b] - what wrong may i have done here

I want to print 0.8745

Comment: Try `text.split(':')[1].strip()`

Answer (score 0):

`find` is a function and not a slicer. You should instead

```
d = text[a+1 : b].strip()
```